# Pegar parte específica de uma string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

Fala galerinha, tudo bom?

Alguém consegue dar uma força? Estou precisando capturar uma parte específica da string que eu puxo de um pdf.

Precisava que conseguisse capturar a parte do código separada por delimitadores (espaços), entendem?

Exemplo:

Valores: 2.155,85D 230,24D 11,16D 2.481,32 88,02 84,07D

Precisava capturar cada um desses valores separadamente, de forma que ficasse:

- Valor 1: 2.155,85D
- Valor 2: 230,24D
- Valor 3: 11,16

Obs: Esse texto fica no final da página, então precisava que ele puxasse da direita pra esquerda, começando pelo final da string.

E assim por diante..
Obrigado galera!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método [Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) da classe [String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) com um espaço em branco para que o mesmo procure as ocorrências e divida esse texto em partes:

***VbNet***

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim texto As String = "2.155,85D 230,24D 11,16D 2.481,32 88,02 84,07D"
    Dim split As String() = texto.Split(" ")
    Console.WriteLine(split(0))
    Console.WriteLine(split(1))
    Console.WriteLine(split(2))
    Console.WriteLine(split(3))
    Console.WriteLine(split(4))
    Console.WriteLine(split(5))
    End Sub
End Module
```

***Csharp***

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string texto = "2.155,85D 230,24D 11,16D 2.481,32 88,02 84,07D";
        string[] split = texto.Split(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(split[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(split[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(split[2]);
    }
}
```

lembrando que é criado um `array` de texto onde cada parte tem o seu próprio indice que é iniciado com 0, para saber o total é só utilizar split.Length que vai informar a quantidade de posições dentro desse `array`.

Comment: Valeuu, deletei os comentários (vou deletar esse também)